# social media icons with overlay

Tags: html, css, icons, social-media, overlays

i've just made social media icons for my website. i wanted to look them a bit more interesting, so i put overlays on them, which appears, when you moving the hover over it.
i've tried to use

```
#bla:hover {
background-image: overlay.png;
}
```

but it didn't worked. Link here: http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/

I also tried this (sorry i cannot really explain :D): http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/website/
But this still did not work well, and looked awful in ie and ff.

do not mind the position of the social media bar.
the overlay should have a transition.

thank you in advance

Comment: Why didn't use `SVG` it's much easier

Comment: @MujtabaFathel hm i never used this before :(

Comment: instead of using image you can use the Font Awesome icons.. very easy to maintain it and it also scalable. http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#web-application

Comment: Use now given solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/78P4v/2/) ..

### CSS

```
.social-item{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
.social-item .original{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.social-item .over{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.social-item:hover .over{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="social-item">
    <img src="http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/website/img/socialmedia/fb.png" class="original" />
    <img src="http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/website/img/socialmedia/fbhover.png" class="over" />
</div>

<div class="social-item">
    <img src="http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/website/img/socialmedia/twitter.png" class="original" />
    <img src="http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/website/img/socialmedia/twitterhover.png" class="over" />
</div>

<div class="social-item">
    <img src="http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/website/img/socialmedia/google.png" class="original" />
    <img src="http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/website/img/socialmedia/googlehover.png" class="over" />
</div>
```

Hope this will help you ..

Comment: this is really cool. updated it: http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test/website/ now it's just have to be inline

Comment: @user3838625 I've updated `.social-item` in **CSS**, to put the three items inline

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some css like I did for facebook overlay

```
#overlayfb {
position: absolute;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
z-index: 1;
background-image: url(img/socialmedia/fbhover.png);
top: -25px;
}
```

top in -25px;

use this
    #overlayfb:hover {
        top: -25px;
    }

I think it will work for you

Comment: the fb icon is bigger now, but there's still no overlay on it

Answer (score 0):

According to your style above, instead of that you should use

```
#bla:hover {
background-image: url('overlay.png');
}
```

The url inside should have the correct location.

Regarding the position, you need to make the div which contain the overlay.png should be absolute. [position: absolute; top: 0;]

And make sure the parent a should be relative or absolute

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
#fb {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-image: url(img/socialmedia/fbhover.png);
}
```

in your style.css (line 72) thats causing the `background-image` to be applied automatically. Instead, you would want something like:

```
#fb {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

#fb:hover {
    background-image: url(...);
}
```

However, I doubt this is what you want. Setting a `background-image` on an `<img src="foo.png">` will just show the `background-image` behind `foo.png`, and I'm guessing you want to replace the image entirely.

So you have two options:

1) Easier: Use jQuery's `.hover()` and `.attr("")` change the `src` of the `<img>` with Javascript.

2) Harder / Uglier (but doesn't require JS): Make two divs, one on top of the other. Make your default image be on the bottom and the hover one be on the top. Set the top div's opacity to 0 and then do a CSS `:hover` selector that changes the top div's opacity to 1. Frankly, I'd go with the first option.